# Pandas Groupby datetime by multiple hours

Tags: time-series, pandas, groupby

I have a log dataset which looks like the following:-

```
   Time                 event
2020-08-27 07:00:00       1
2020-08-27 08:34:00       1
2020-08-27 16:42:23       1 
2020-08-27 23:19:11       1
             .
             .
             .
```

I am trying to get the count of events that happened within different hourly interval (6 hours, 8 hours etc). Any ideas on how I can get it done pandas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Grouper function. With the `freq` argument, you can set the time interval. The example is for 6 hours.

```
dfcounts = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='6H')).count()
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the simplest solution that gets me the desired result

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use `pd.cut` to create your desired bins and then count your observations grouped by the created bins.

````py
from faker import Faker
from datetime import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

# Create sample dataframe
fake = Faker()
n = 100
start = dt(2020, 1, 1, 7, 0, 0)
end = dt(2020, 1, 1, 23, 0, 0)
df = pd.DataFrame({"datetime": [fake.date_time_between(start_date=start, end_date=end) for _ in range(n)]})

# Create bins
bins = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='2H')
df["bins"] = pd.cut(df.datetime, bins=bins)

# Count grouped observations
df.groupby("bins").count().rename(columns={"datetime": "counts"})
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to give the dates between which you want to count the events, extract the indexes and compute the sum of events.

Here is a code sample:

````
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# This is only for fake dataframe generation
def pp(start, end, n):
    start_u = start.value//10**9
    end_u = end.value//10**9

    return pd.DatetimeIndex((10**9*np.random.randint(start_u, end_u, n, dtype=np.int64)).view('M8[ns]'))

start = pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01 00:00:00')
end = pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01 23:59:59')
fake_date = pp(start, end, 100)

# Fake dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0, 5, 100), index=fake_date, columns=['event'])

# Date between which you want to compute the number of event
start_d = pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01 06:00:00')
end_d = pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01 12:00:00')

indexNames = df[ (df.index >= start_d) & (df.index <= end_d) ].index
print( df['event'].loc[indexNames].sum() )
```
````